# NSString seems empty, but isn't

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsstring

I'm trying to read a textfile into a NSString. Something really weird is happening as it seems the code loads the whole text into the NSString (the lenght is correct), but when I NSLog the string-content it only shows the first character.

```
NSError *error;
    NSStringEncoding encoding = 0;
    NSString *textFile = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url
                                                        encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                           error:&error];
    
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"TEXT length %lu", (unsigned long)textFile.length);
        NSLog(@"TEXT  %@", textFile);
    }
```

This logs the following to the console:

```
2014-02-14 14:46:21.308 iCaching[4055:303] TEXT length 4968
2014-02-14 14:46:37.630 iCaching[4055:303] TEXT  G
```

But when I split the NSString in an array of substrings separated by newline, it returns the correct number of strings. But logging the content of these substrings is empty again.

```
if (textFile && !error) {
        
        NSArray *visitsArray = [textFile componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
        NSLog(@"visits count %lu", (unsigned long)[visitsArray count]);
```

This logs:

```
visits count 63
```

Looking in the debugger first reveals a content of @"G",

[image]

but using quicklook shows the entire (correct) content of the NSString.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps the text is UTF-16 encoded, so that every second byte is zero. Try NSUTF16StringEncoding, or one of its little/big-endian variants.

Comment: That's it: NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding. Thanks!

Comment: Tried to upvote your comment, but that didn't work :-(

Comment: @MartinR you should repeat your comment as an answer so this question can be green checked (as a bonus, you'll get more points :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(From my above comment:)* The text is probably UTF-16 encoded, so that every second byte is zero. Try `NSUTF16StringEncoding`, or one of its little/big-endian variants.

Answer (score 0):

I think yours file have UNICODE encoding.
In UNICODE chacacters have two bites. "G" writen as 0x47,0x00.
You are readin file as UTF-8. For UTF-8 after 'G' comes line end.
Try use `NSUnicodeStringEncoding`.

Comment: if it's this it's a nice answer!

Comment: No sorry. That didn't help. The content becomes a mess of 'chineese' chars and the array of substrings counts 1. I already tried NSUTFStringEncoding and NSASCIIStringEncoding